# How to access sbt managed resource in Scala program

Tags: scala, sbt

I create a managed resource through the following code in build.sbt:

```
resourceGenerators in Compile <+=
  (resourceManaged in Compile, name, version) map { (dir, n, v) =>
    val file = dir / "version"
    val contents = Process("git rev-parse HEAD").lines.head
    IO.write(file, contents)
    Seq(file)
  }
```

I can see it well created under `target/scala-2.11/resource_managed/main`

I extract its contents in my application as follows:

```
  val version = getClass.getResource("version")
  println(Source.fromURL(version).mkString)
```

I wonder if there's a Scala class for accessing resources, that is more preferable than Java's `getClass.getResource`

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. What's the problem with `getClass.getResource`?

Comment: I guess this is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks guys, just checking..

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in the comment, I think this is the correct approach, and there is no other equivalent method in Scala.

However, I would recommend you to look at the [sbt-buildinfo](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo) plugin, which in your case would allow you to place the version string directly in a synthetic Scala object.

Comment: well I didn't manage to fiddle that plugin to feed from a "Process" command, and it's also a slower approach so it seems. Managing resources seems just more lightweight right now.

Comment: `BuildInfoKey.action("version")(Process(...).lines.head)`